# Display custom field on wordpress in order

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I have a situation here where the array custom fields that I got is not in order. May I know how to have all custom fields in order?

The function that I use to get the custom array is:

```
$title = get_post_meta($post_id, "cap-display_name", false);
foreach($title as $a){
    echo 'hello '.$a.'<br><br>';
}
```

However, the output that I got is:

```
hello this is first 

hello this is second 

hello this is third

hello this is six 

hello this is four 

hello this is five 

hello this is seven
```

**The supposed output is:**

```
hello this is first

hello this is second

hello this is third

hello this is four

hello this is five

hello this is six

hello this is seven
```

May I know how to get the above output?

print_r($title) will get this:

Array ( [0] => this is first [1] => this is second [2] => this is third [3] => this is six [4] => this is four [5] => this is five [6] => this is seven )

Comment: show the structure of your array, `print_r($title)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to run your custom SQL for this. Something like this:

```
   global $wpdb; // your DB object
   $sql = "SELECT m.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta m where m.meta_key = 'cap-display_name' and m.post_id = {$post_id} order by m.meta_id";
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
   foreach( $results as $result )
   {
      echo 'hello '.$result->meta_value.'<br><br>';
   }
```